# SVN checkout the contents of a folder, not the folder itself

Tags: linux, svn, svn-checkout

I'm fairly new to linux and svn. I'm trying to checkout the trunk folder of a project into my public_html directory using this command (while in public_html):

```
svn checkout file:///home/landonwinters/svn/waterproject/trunk
```

The waterproject directory contains the files from untarring a base install of drupal.

It checks out fine, except all the files are in `public_html/trunk` instead of just being in `public_html`.

I don't know the command to move all the contents of trunk up to public_html and rm trunk, but I think I could figure that out relatively easily. I just want to know if I can just check out the contents of a folder, without the folder itself.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

Just add a `.` to it:

```
svn checkout file:///home/landonwinters/svn/waterproject/trunk .
```

That means: check out to current directory.

Comment: Also have a look at the cvs command line reference: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re04.html

Answer (score 22):

```
svn co svn://path destination
```

To specify current directory, use a "." for your destination directory:

```
svn checkout file:///home/landonwinters/svn/waterproject/trunk .
```

Answer (score 11):

Just add the directory on the command line:

```
svn checkout svn://192.168.1.1/projectname/ target-directory/
```

Answer (score 10):

Provide the directory on the command line:

```
svn checkout file:///home/landonwinters/svn/waterproject/trunk public_html
```

Comment: If you specify an existing directory it will create a new folder with the name of the root checkout directory there, while if you specify a non-existant folder, it will use that instead.

Comment: You can avoid overriding files by renaming an existing directory, checking out and renaming it back again.