# SVN checkout the contents of a folder, not the folder itself

Tags: svn

i want to checkout my WebRoot folder content not WebRoot folder itself.

i import  my content by

there is two folder in /tmp/easton is src and WebRoot

svn import -m 'import source files' /tmp/easton svn://209.235.175.18/easton/

i try

svn checkout svn://209.235.175.18/easton/WebRoot

but it create WebRoot folder to my easton directory. i want to add the content of webroot folder not itsself folder webroot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN checkout the contents of a folder, not the folder itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927806/svn-checkout-the-contents-of-a-folder-not-the-folder-itself)

Answer (score 1):

The intention you have does not work. Cause SVN needs a separate directory where to checkout to. so i would suggest to checkout it like the following

```
svn checkout svn://209.235.175.18/easton/  checkout-folder
```

This will create the checkout-folder with the contents of easton folder from your repository.

Answer (score 1):

To checkout just content of your svn folder, just add a dot at the end of your command:

```
svn checkout svn://209.235.175.18/easton/WebRoot .
```

To checkout just content of your svn folder into your local folder:

```
svn checkout svn://209.235.175.18/easton/WebRoot /home/seval/my_project_folder
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens when you omit the PATH part of `svn checkout` command. Check out (hehe) the manual: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re04.html

Answer (score 0):

ya i did by

svn checkout svn://209.235.175.18/easton/WebRoot /var/www/html/easton